# Альтернатива PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, java

По приходу пуша показываю нотификацию, при этом надо включить на пару секунд экран.

Использую в сервисе следующий код:

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if(!pm.isScreenOn())
    {
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE
                , "MyLock");
        wl.acquire(5000);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что `PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK` помечен как **deprecated**, и советуют использовать `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`. Вот так:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Но как я могу получить доступ к окну из сервиса? Тем более, что девайс спит.
Существует ли альтернатива `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`?

Comment: А как апнуть вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте прозрачное активити и вызывайте его из сервиса с флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

В onCreate() активити используйте следующие флаги:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

После разблокировки экрана закройте активити.